# reticulate R package does not find python installation (Sys.which("python") returns empty str)

Tags: rstudio, reticulate

I am trying to use Python within Rstudio (1.2.5*) using the `reticulate` package on a Windows 10 computer. I installed Python via Anaconda, but it seems that reticulate (or base R) can not find it.

```
library(reticulate)
Sys.which("python")
```

Which returns:

```
python 
    ""
```

Should I interpret that python was not found?
How can I solve this?

Anaconda installation recommended not to save the PATH, so I did not, perhaps that is the problem

Comment: This is not related to reticulate. `Sys.which` is base R function. If it can't find Python, it means you haven't set Python in your environment vairables.